# Why this works in arrow func, and not regular func?

Tags: javascript

I wanted to pass the width and height values of the window to the only canvas tag in html, and also keep pass the values whenever the window viewport is changed or changing.

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');



//   Why does this work?
const getViewport = ()=> { 
    [canvas.width , canvas.height] = [window.innerWidth , window.innerHeight];
    console.log(canvas.width);
    console.log(canvas.height);
};


// Why this doesn't work?
function getViewport() {
    [canvas.width , canvas.height] = [window.innerWidth , window.innerHeight];
    console.log(canvas.width);
    console.log(canvas.height);
};

/* I used this with arrow function, tried this on regular function
and did't work so I tried below code */
window.onresize = getViewport;


/* This only runs on the first time when the window is loaded, and
does not run after when i change the window size */
window.onresize = getViewport();
```

Comment: There's no obvious reason that the arrow function would work when the function declaration wouldn't. You must have changed some other factor.

Comment: can you please edit the question so that we can see 1) a full code sample (as small as possible to reproduce the issue) which doesn't work (using the arrow function) 2) a similar one, with the non-arrow function, which does work. Right now it's not clear what code you were actually running, especially as there is a big difference between assigning `getViewport` and `getViewport()`.

Answer (score -2):

The reason is that the arrow function is an expression, i.e. it evaluates to a value, whereas your function below is a function declaration, which means it doesn't evaluate to a value, it's a reference to let's say a future value that will be evaluated when the function is called.

Comment: This is not the reason. The arrow function should work the same as the regular function in this case. Also, the fact that arrow functions are function expressions does not mean "they evaluate to a value". Function expressions also exist (`const myFunc = function(a,b) { return a + b }`)